Total Variation between Conditional Probabilities
Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two probability measures on a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $S$. Take $E\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mu_1(E),\mu_2(E)>0$. Define two probability measures $\widetilde{\mu}_1$ and $\widetilde{\mu}_2$ on $(S,\mathcal{S})$ by
$$
\widetilde{\mu}_i(A) = \frac{\mu_i(A\cap E)}{\mu_i(E)},\qquad\forall\,A\in\mathcal{S},\quad\forall\,i=1,2.
$$
Can we say anything about the relation between the total variation distances $\text{TV}(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and $\text{TV}(\widetilde{\mu}_1,\widetilde{\mu}_2)$? Here $\text{TV}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is defined by $\text{TV}(\mu,\nu) = \sup\{|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|:A\in\mathcal{S}\}$.
Intuitively, I would expect $\text{TV}(\widetilde{\mu}_1,\widetilde{\mu}_2) \le C\cdot \text{TV}(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ for some constant $C\ge 0$ that depends on $\mu_1(E)$ and $\mu_2(E)$. However, I do not know where to start.

Let $\lambda$ be a finite reference measure so that $\mu_i \ll \lambda $ for $i = 1, 2$. (For example, set $\lambda = \mu_1 + \mu_2$.) Then it is well-known that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{TV}(\mu_1, \mu_2) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{S} |p_1(x) - p_2(x)| \, \lambda(\mathrm{d}x),  
\end{align*}
where $p_i = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu_i}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative. (This is not hard to prove! Check that the supremum in the definition of TV is maximized when $A = \{p_1 \geq p_2\}$.)
Now, assume WLOG that $\mu_1(E) \leq \mu_2(E)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{TV}(\tilde{\mu}_1, \tilde{\mu}_2)
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{E} \left| \frac{p_1(x)}{\mu_1(E)} - \frac{p_2(x)}{\mu_2(E)}\right| \, \lambda(\mathrm{d}x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\mu_1(E)\mu_2(E)} \int_{E} \left| \mu_2(E) p_1(x) - \mu_1(E)p_2(x)\right| \, \lambda(\mathrm{d}x) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\mu_1(E)\mu_2(E)} \int_{E} \left( \left| \mu_2(E) - \mu_1(E) \right| p_1(x) + \mu_1(E)\left| p_1(x) - p_2(x)\right| \right) \, \lambda(\mathrm{d}x)  \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\mu_1(E)\mu_2(E)} \cdot 3\mu_1(E) \int_{E} \left| p_1(x) - p_2(x)\right| \, \lambda(\mathrm{d}x) \\
&\leq \frac{3}{\mu_2(E)} \operatorname{TV}(\mu_1, \mu_2).
\end{align*}
Therefore we get
$$ \operatorname{TV}(\tilde{\mu}_1, \tilde{\mu}_2)
\leq C \cdot \operatorname{TV}(\mu_1, \mu_2)
\quad\text{with}\quad
C = \frac{3}{\max\{\mu_1(E), \mu_2(E)\}}. $$

Addendum. We can show that there is no absolute constant $C$ making the inequality hold true in any cases. Consequently, we cannot avoid making $C$ as a function of $\mu_i(E)$'s. (But the above bound is likely far from being optimal.)
Indeed, set $S = [0, 1]$, and for each $a \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$ we set
$$ \mu_1(\mathrm{d}x) = \left( 2\cdot\mathbf{1}[x \leq a] + \frac{1-2a}{1-a} \mathbf{1}[x > a] \right) \, \mathrm{d}x,
\qquad \mu_2(\mathrm{d}x) = \mathrm{d}x. $$
Then it is easy to check that
$$ \operatorname{TV}(\mu_1, \mu_2) = a. $$
However, if we set $E = [0, 2a]$, then
$$ \operatorname{TV}(\tilde{\mu}_1, \tilde{\mu}_2) = \frac{1}{6-8a}. $$
This shows that $ \frac{\operatorname{TV}(\tilde{\mu}_1, \tilde{\mu}_2)}{\operatorname{TV}(\mu_1, \mu_2)}$ is not bounded above.

To the downvoter, could you kindly guide me how I should improve my answer?

(+1) It boggles the mind why someone can downvote your answer without an explanation, which is very concise and clear by the way.

(+1) Great answer! It seems that the term $3\mu_1(E)$ in the second last inequality should be $2\mu_1(E)$?
